# jquery colorbox call following ajax load not working

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm loading in some image using .load . I want to then click on these images and invoke colorbox. I have tried the following:

```
 $("a[rel='colorbox']").live('click',
      function() {
          $(this).colorbox({transition:"fade"});
      }
 );
```

But with no joy. Any ideas out there?

Comment: A bit of warning, the live function in JQuery has been deprecated. You should use the on syntax which is $("a[rel='colorbox']").on('click', function () {})

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you shouldn't use `.live()` it's deprecated. Instead learn how to use `.on()` You'll find this is a much more powerful listener and will help solve your problem.

On page load initially the DOM is ready, and colorbox is initilized for the selector
AJAX calls a new piece of the page with some DOM element that is in the colorbox selector list, but isn't noticed because it loaded into the page after the selector was read by the javascript.

Try the following - as it watches `body` for all, existing and new `#main a[rel='lightbox']`:

EDIT:

```
$("body").on("click", "#main a[rel='lightbox']", function(event){
  $.colorbox({href: $(this).attr("href"),
 transition: "fade",
 innerHeight: '515px',
 innerWidth: '579px',
 overlayClose: true,
 iframe: true,
 opacity: 0.3
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you asserted that $("a[rel='colorbox']").length>0?

Edit: Try this and see if clicking the link in question triggers a breakpoint:

```
$("a[rel='colorbox']").live('click',
      function() {
          debugger;
          $(this).colorbox({transition:"fade"});
      }
 );
```

If it doesn't break, then the the link is not mached by the selector (a[rel='colorbox']). If it does, then the problem probably does not have anything to do with your use of the load()

Comment: Well - I tried this on three elements not using .load (hard coded in) and it worked ok: 
$("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({transition:"fade"});

Comment: @squeaker: In that case write "debugger;" inside the click even handler function and see if the breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example please?

Comment: Not giving much back - could the problem be related to the click activating the 'a href' - I guess i need to add in event.preventDefault(); or somthing?

Comment: Thanks for you tips, Almost there now - prevent default helped, but now I'm having to click twice to activate colorbox from the image